# TimerTask and setting Views on UI Thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, runnable, timertask

I'm trying to detect a user long click using a TimerTask. The code isnide the runnable should be executed whenthe user holds the button for longer than the LONG_PRESS_TIMEOUT variable. The short click event works, however when executing the below code, when the TimerTask is invoked, I get the error `Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.`

```
 View.OnTouchListener detectClickAndHoldListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {

        private Timer timer = new Timer();
        private long LONG_PRESS_TIMEOUT = 1337; // TODO: your timeout here
        private boolean wasLong = false;

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            Log.d(getClass().getName(), "touch event: " + event.toString());

            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                // touch & hold started
                timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        wasLong = true;
                        snap.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cam_rec);
                        try {
                            initRecorder(mCameraView.getHolder().getSurface());
                            mMediaRecorder.start();

                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        // touch & hold was long
                    }
                }, LONG_PRESS_TIMEOUT);
                return true;
            }

            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                // touch & hold stopped
                timer.cancel();
                if(!wasLong){
                    mCamera.takePicture(shutterCallback, rawCallback, jpegCallback);
                    snap.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.filled_cam);
                }
                else {
                    mMediaRecorder.stop();
                    mMediaRecorder.reset();
                }
                timer = new Timer();
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
    };
```

Comment: Exactly as it says. You cannot touch **ANY** UI element off the UI thread.

Comment: Yes, how would I alter the above code to still fulfill the described task whilst not encountering this problem?

Comment: This is exactly why you should not use `Timer` in Android.  It's a non-Android class that exists in the API to support legacy Java libraries, not new Android code.

Comment: I was proposed this answer on here http://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/58916584?noredirect=1 to a question concerning detecting a hold and release as opposed to a short click event

Comment: Yeah, I proposed that answer. Can you give more detail on Timer drawbacks, @KevinKrumwiede?

@mankee, you can only touch views on UI thread, that means you should post a runnable touching your views to Activity.runOnUiThread

Comment: @xAF if I do that how can I still use the timer functionality to detect the longclick?

Comment: @xAF It's mainly that `Timer` is an extremely heavyweight solution to doing simple things at intervals.  It involves an additional thread and the associated thread safety issues.  Those thread safety concerns are the reason you're prohibited from touching the UI outside the UI thread.  But why the OP is trying to use a `Timer` at all is a mystery to me.  It seems like this question is really about how to detect a long click.

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede I need to be able to detect the user releasing from the longClick, and also a normal short click. This is why I use the timer to differentiate between them

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede I happen to use Timer occasionally in time-dependent-UI-updating situations, like when you need to update a counter or progressBar at certain frequency, mostly with scheduleAtFixedRate. Hence the question, thanks!

Comment: @xAF The "Android way" is to use `Handler#postDelayed(...)`.  You can achieve a fixed frequency by checking the elapsed time and adjusting the delay each time the update task re-queues itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
YourActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
@Override
public void run(){
    try {
             initRecorder(mCameraView.getHolder().getSurface());
             mMediaRecorder.start();
    } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
);
```

Comment: Yes but how does this make use of the timer and detects the long click?

Comment: This code will run only in case of the long click, if you put it inside your run() method of TimerTask